# Installing LIGGGHTS Software on Ubuntu 20.04 Problem

Tags: 20.04, compiling, open-source

While installing LIGGGHTS in Ubuntu, I am facing the following problem. Can anyone please tell me what is going on?

'''

> lm_lab@slmlab-VirtualBox:~/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src$ make auto Creating
> list of contact models completed. make[1]: Entering directory
> '/home/slm_lab/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src/Obj_auto' Makefile:945: *** 'Could
> not determine suitable appendix of VTK library with
> VTK_INC="-I../../lib/vtk/install/include/vtk-8.0",
> VTK_LIB="-L/home/liggghts/vtk/lib" and VTK_APPENDIX="-8.0"'. Stop.
> make[1]: Leaving directory
> '/home/slm_lab/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/src/Obj_auto' make: *** [Makefile:114:
> auto] Error 2

'''

Comment: https://www.cfdem.com/forum

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have already posted them in the forum but didn't get a satisfactory response. I believe the problem is with the Ubuntu environment or directory. That's why looking for some solution.

Comment: If the devs don't know/don't care why their code doesn't compile in one of the mainstream distros there's no way random people in the internet will know more.